# recall the construct in codigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to recall the construct as it contains all the required data for the page?

```
class Abc extends CI_Controller
{
       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('xyz_m');
            $this->data['info'] = $this->xyz_m->get(); //get data
       }

       public function 123()
       {
          /*view page code*/
       }

       public function 456()
       {
          /*insert code here*/

          $this->123(); // redirect, need to load 123() with updated data from construct.
       }
}
```

So, how do you make the __construct initiate again so you get a new updated results from database?

Answer (score 1):

You should name your methods with letter first i.e. there is convention for method names uses descriptive words `getProducts()` or `get_books` or you will get PHP error for using numbers as method names. So in your case method names should be like `a123()` or `b_456()`.
Second thing, regarding your need in question, since you assign data from DB using model to array `$this->data`, you would use it like:

```
class Abc extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('xyz_m');
        $this->data['info'] = $this->xyz_m->get(); //get data
    }

    public function a123()
    {
        $this->load->view('a123_view', $this->data);//loading file APPPATH . 'a123_view.php' and passing created array to it
    }

    public function b_456()
    {
        /*insert code here*/

        $this->a123(); // redirect, need to load 123() with updated data from construct.
    }
}
```

In your `APPPATH . 'a123_view.php'`:

```
<?php var_dump($info);//here you would call key of array you passed from controller as variable ?>
```

Check basics in [CodeIgniter documentations](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/index.html). All this is described in [General Topics section](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/index.html).

Comment: may be your mistake write method name is wrong $this->123() instead of pass $this->a123()  in b_456() body...

Comment: @RadadiyaAnkur Yup, it's fixed now. Thanks.